# Pythonで添付ファイルをメールの行内に貼る方法

Tags: python

ネットで調べたのですがなかなか対処法が見つからないので、こちらで質問させていただきます。

現在、Pythonとwin32comでメールを自動送付するツールを作成しているのですが、リッチテキスト形式での実行のため、文中にファイルを添付しようと考えています。

想定

```
以下にファイルを添付します。
{添付ファイル}　
よろしくお願いします。
```

使用コード

```
outlook =  = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.createItemFromTemplate(template_item)

mail.to = ""
mail.cc = ""
mail.bcc = ""
mail.bodyformat = 3 # 3: リッチテキスト
mail.Attachment.Add(attachment)
mail.Display(True)
```

しかし上記のコードの場合、すべてのファイルがメールの最下部に添付されてしまいます。あらかじめ決めた場所に{}を書き込み、format()で挿入も考えましたが、ファイル名が書き込まれるのみでした。
行内にファイルを添付するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: Body プロパティを使うとどうでしょうか [MailItem.Body プロパティ (Outlook) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) テキストの内容を読み込んで、それを mail.body に設定すればよさそうです

Comment: このVBAのQ&A記事でやっているようなことをPythonで実現すれば良いのでは？ [How to Embed a PDF Document in an Email Message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44598984/9014308)

Comment: @kunif 返信ありがとうございます。試してみましたがアイコンの表示がおかしいことや、ファイル名が表示されないことが起こりました。

Comment: @miwarin 返信ありがとうございます。テキストとは添付ファイルのことでしょうか？

Comment: @Ryuhei さん、そういえば添付ファイルのファイルタイプや内容は何なのでしょう？ それによっては必要なAPIが変わるのかもしれませんね。

Comment: python 標準ライブラリーでならできるけど, win32com (outlook) 限定ですか？

Comment: @oriri 特にOutlookです。

Comment: @kunif 主にpdfやtxtなどといったドキュメントファイルです。

Comment: 「テキスト」(txtと同じ)は添付ファイルのつもりでした。が、添付ファイルにはテキスト以外もあるんですね。PDFやWordといったファイルも含まれるんですね。そうすると、うーん。

Answer (score 1):

Attachment.Addの前にDisplayを実行することで、任意の行内にファイルを添付することができました。

```
mail.to = ""
mail.cc = ""
mail.bcc = ""
mail.bodyformat = 3
mail.Display(True) # タイミングを変える
mail.Attachment.Add(Source=attachment,Position=position)
```